# How to write in a new shader file in SceneKit: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, shader, scenekit

I am beginning with SceneKit and the shaders, I created a swift file, changed its name for myFragment.shader, and I added this :

```
uniform sampler2D RTBlurH; // this should hold the texture rendered by the horizontal blur pass
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
const float blurSize = 1.0/512.0;

sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y - 4.0*blurSize)) * 0.05;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y - 3.0*blurSize)) * 0.09;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y - 2.0*blurSize)) * 0.12;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y - blurSize)) * 0.15;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y)) * 0.16;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y + blurSize)) * 0.15;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y + 2.0*blurSize)) * 0.12;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y + 3.0*blurSize)) * 0.09;
sum += texture2D(RTBlurH, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y + 4.0*blurSize)) * 0.05;

gl_FragColor = sum;
```

from the blur tutorial [here](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/)

But I get 3 errors on the 3 first lines : it asks me to add a `;` :

[image]

I don't understand the problem.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, this is a really terrible way to do blur on a mobile GPU. Eight dependent texture reads per fragment will kill your performance on some devices (and merely wound it on others). [Here's a good writeup](http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu) on doing blur on a mobile GPU. Note also that in SceneKit, you can just assign a Core Image filter to a node and let Apple handle the blur implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a swift file, changed its name for myFragment.shader

That's your problem.

When you add a file to your project, Xcode determines how it'll process it when building based on what type of file it is. If you create a Swift file, it'll compile it with the Swift compiler. (And the Swift compiler will expect the contents of that file to be written in Swift, not GLSL.)

You don't want your shaders compiled as native (CPU) source. Shaders are compiled (for the GPU) by OpenGL when your app runs, so you just copy them into your bundle and pass them to GL (via SceneKit, in your case) when you're ready to use them.

The file processing rules in your project don't automatically change when you rename a file's type extension. (This is because you can reasonably use different extensions than Xcode's defaults for some file types.) So, here are two fixes for two different contexts:

#### Change the build rule for an existing file

For what you've got, you probably don't want to recreate parts of your project, you just want to tell Xcode to treat your shader as a shader, not a Swift source. Choose your project in the navigator, go to Build Phases, and move `myFragment.shader` from Compile Sources to Copy Bundle Resources.

[image]

#### Add a new file with the right build rule

You can avoid the above when creating new shader files. If you create a new file using the *Empty* file template, it'll be treated as a bundle resource already, so you don't need to do anything further.

[image]

Likewise, if you drag a `.shader` or `.fsh` or `.vsh` (or really anything else that's not a Swift/C/ObjC/etc source file) into your project, that'll be treated as a bundle resource by default.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to rickster's answer, note that you can change the type of any file using the File Inspector in Xcode :

[image]

By selecting "OpenGL Shading Language source" you'll obtain code completion and correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: Note that *only* gets you code completion and syntax highlighting — you still need to set the Build Rules correctly to get your file copied as a bundle resource instead of compiled as Swift/C/whatever.